# How do I install Tensorflow for R on Windows 10

Tags: python, r, tensorflow

please I want to install tensorflow for R on my windows10 computer. I have run the code `install_tensorflow()` and `use_condaenv("r-tensorflow")` from the reticulate library but I get the error message below:

```
Error: Error installing package(s): "tensorflow==2.4"
```

I have also tried to install tensorflow in my command prompt using `pip3 install tensorflow` command, but I also get the error message below:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

Please, is there a way around it. I have also installed the latest version of anaconda and python 3.8 on my computer. I will really appreciate any help I can get

Comment: @msanford From the link you provide *"TensorFlow is distributed as a Python package [...]"*.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
install.packages("tensorflow")
```

PS Do this inside your R program of course.

Comment: Yes, I have done install.packages("tensorflow") in R, after which I run the the install_tensorflow() command, which gives me that error message in the console.

Comment: Try confirming your installation by: 
library(tensorflow)
tf$constant("Hellow Tensorflow")

Comment: It printed this message in my console:

tf$constant("Hellow Tensorflow")
Error: Python module tensorflow was not found.

Detected Python configuration:

python:         C:/Users/IFEANYI/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/IFEANYI/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/python37.dll
pythonhome:     C:/Users/IFEANYI/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate
version:        3.7.10 (default, Feb 26 2021, 13:06:18) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit

Comment: try this and let's hope it works: install_tensorflow(method = "conda", envname = "Tensorflow_for_R") 
Recheck installation

Comment: I ran that code and it said "Installation complete" "Restarting R session". However, I still got the error message above after I ran the tf$constant("Hellow Tensorflow") code

Comment: I think your TensorFlow is getting successfully installed in the environment, you need to activate the environment before running the TensorFlow library.

Comment: How do I activate the environment, so that I can run the tensorflow library?

Comment: 1. Create a new conda environment with all the r-essentials conda packages built from CRAN: 
conda create -n r_env r-essentials r-base

2. Activate the environment:
conda activate r_env

3. List the packages in the environment ( in your case TensorFlow should be listed)
conda list

More details: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/using-r-language/

Comment: Thanks. After creating a new conda environment, will I need to start a new project in R Studio?